# What steps need to be taken to get autocomplete working for React Native in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I have followed the steps outlined in the VS Code documentation for getting Intellisense working for React Native by installing typings for React Native. Now, what do I need to do to get autocomplete working? For instance, if I type `<Text>`, I would like to see an automatic closing of that tag. What am I missing here? This seems like it shuld work out of the box.

Answer (score 16):

To enable IntelliSense (*autocomplete*) you have to install the official [React Native Tools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native) extension.

**Installation**

Open Command Palette by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `ext install` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then look for **React Native Tools** extension.

**Create a jsconfig.json file**

You should create a `jsconfig.json` file in you root directory. It can be empty but must be present. The presence of such a file in a directory indicates that the directory is the root of a JavaScript project.

(*Optional*)

The file itself can optionally list the files belonging to the project, the files to be excluded from the project, as well as compiler options.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

You can find more at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson

**Create a .babelrc file for ReactNative Packger transformer** (*optional, if you want to use TypeScript*)

You should create a `.babelrc` file with `sourceMaps = true` and `"presets": [ "react-native" ]` for better source-mapping support. (*required if you want TypeScript support*).

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native" // this is required for debugging with react-native/packager/transformer
  ],
  "plugins": [],
  "sourceMaps": true // must be true react-native/packager/transformer using with node-module-debug
  // because of some bugs from vscode-node-debug & vscode-react-native, "sourceMaps" cannot be "inline" or "both"
}
```

**Install typings for React Native** (*optional*)

To get IntelliSense for React Native, run `npm install typings -g` and then  `typings install dt~react-native --global` in your terminal.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 5):

`React Native Tools` in VSCode can't help you close the Tag after you typed`<Text>`,you can try to install [Auto Close Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) and [Auto Rename Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I have to copy jsconfig.json to tsconfig.json, close Visual Code and reopen it. Then it works properly.

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to have the autocomplete enabled for all the files in `scr` **as well as** for the dependencies installed in `node_modules` with `npm install`?

Answer (score 0):

I am also not getting any IntelliSense and also package auto-import is not working. Since I am not using Typescript, deleting the `tsconfig.json` helped me.

**Take backup of your `tsconfig.json` file first**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've already installed many react-native extensions for autoSuggestion and another helper extension, e.g. "React Native Tools", and "React-Native/React/Redux snippets for es6/es7"

Issues:

- autoSuggestion keywords not coming while typing.
- command(in IOS) + click not letting me to jump on the target files.

Recently I have seen in VS Code editor for new React-native applications autoSuggestion not working.

Steps I have followed to solve:

1. Go to Extensions [image: extension image]
2. Search for React or React-native
3. Remove the installed extension
4. Reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Simply install `npm i -D @types/react-native` & it give auto suggestions to you about react native

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).